# Android: How to get the dimensions of the Image resized to fit into an ImageView?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the dimensions of the Image **resized to fit into an ImageView**. For example, if an image originally has dimensions 400px by  400px but is displayed onto an ImageView with dimensions 350px by 350px, then I should get 350x350 as the dimensions. But I can't just get the ImageView's dimensions, since some images may be resized to fit within the ImageView, as shown in the screenshot below. I want to get the dimensions of the portion highlighted in green.

[image]

So far, I have been trying to retrieve the dimensions of the ImageView's BitMap, but it always returns the dimensions of the image, not the dimensions of the image resized to fit into the ImageView.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/single_screen_photo_compare"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_preview"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:maxHeight="370dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/android"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.changingimageviewwidth;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.apache.sanselan.ImageReadException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView sliderPreviewBox = findViewById(R.id.photo_preview);
        Drawable drawable = sliderPreviewBox.getDrawable();
        Rect bounds = drawable.getBounds();
        int width = bounds.width();
        int height = bounds.height();
        int bitmapWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bitmapHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        System.out.println("[width] = " + width);
        System.out.println("[height] = " + height);
        System.out.println("[bitmapWidth] = " + bitmapWidth);
        System.out.println("[bitmapHeight] = " + bitmapHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the height and width of the image before you put into the ImageView? Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: @skafle But I need to get the dimensions of the image AFTER it is resized to fit into the ImageView. For instance, if the image is 400 x 400 but it is put into an ImageView that is 350 x 350 and resized to fit the ImageView, I want to get width = 350 and height = 350.